# telnet connection to outgoing SMTP server

Tags: smtp, telnet

I can't establish a connection to an outgoing SMTP server. I get this:

```
   telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
   Trying 64.233.190.109...
   telnet: connect to address 64.233.190.109: Operation timed out
   Trying 64.233.190.108...
   telnet: connect to address 64.233.190.108: Operation timed out
   Trying 2800:3f0:4003:c00::6d...
   telnet: connect to address 2800:3f0:4003:c00::6d: No route to host
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

what is going on?

Comment: It can't get to the host, that could be a variety of issues (no network, no route, firewall, etc) but I suspect *all* of them have little to do with programming, so this is probably the wrong forum :-) Nudging over to SF, our sister site for network-related stuff.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't know I was in the wrong place. I just could not find anything on the web. to me, establishing a connection is often a condition to programming. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your ISP is blocking outgoing connections on port 25.  Many ISP's do this to prevent spammers from running mail servers on their networks.  Can you connect to *any* SMTP server on port 25?  Have you tried connecting to smtp.gmail.com on port 587 instead?